# Is it possible to download all packages within a scope with npm?

Tags: npm

I am tasked with pulling down an entire scope into our internal Artifactory but I am seeing no easy way to do this.  For instance, I can download single packages under the required repository -- in this case, `@progress`, but no way to pull all packages within the scope at once, for example:

`npm pack @progress/kendo-popup-common`

But I would like to do something like:

`npm pack @progress/*`

Any suggestions?

Thanks!